# How to resolve the ambiguity of "two day classes"

Tags: ambiguity, numbers, compounds

> Two day classes will take place this week.

Here, "day classes" is a compound. I don't want it to sound like it's just one class that goes on for two days.

Comment: Two of day classes ...

Comment: Consider also "two day-long classes" or "two full-day classes".

Comment: @senshin Your suggestions work if *day* refers to the length of the class, but not if *day class* is for contrast with *night class*, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

*"Two day classes will take place this week."* I understand this to mean that during the week a day class will be held twice. Not necessarily on consecutive days.

*"Two-day classes will take place this week."*  This now means that classes will cover the entire subject over two various or consecutive days.

More useful information about hyphens can be found here:
http://www.grammar-monster.com/punctuation/using_hyphens.htm

Comment: This is good for written text. For speech the difference is clear thanks to the spontaneous placing of a small pause after *two* (first case) or *day* (second case).

Answer (score 0):

"Two one-day classes will take place this week." (and one two-day class next).

Answer (score -1):

How about:
Day classes will take place twice this week